# R optim function fails to find the minimum

Tags: r

I have a function with one variable and want to find the minimum value. The code is like below:

```
# Set the constants
KA <- 1.0E-09
KB <- 1.0E-08
KC <- 1.0E-07
Rtotal <- 1.0E-08
Atotal <- 1.0E-08
Btotal <- 1.0E-08
Ctotal <- 1.0E-08

#Create a function
error_f <- function(Rfree) {

Afree <- Atotal * KA / (Rfree + KA)
Bfree <- Btotal * KB / (Rfree + KB)
Cfree <- Ctotal * KB / (Rfree + KC)

RA <- Atotal - Afree
RB <- Btotal - Bfree
RC <- Ctotal - Cfree

estimated_Rtotal <- Rfree + RA + RB + RC
return((estimated_Rtotal - Rtotal)^2)

}
```

I know that I can get the minimum value for this function when the variable Rfree is ~1.8E-09. I confirmed it by creating pairs of Rfree & error_f(Rfree) as described in the code below, and plotting the result. You can see the plot from the link below the code.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- seq(1.0E-09, 5.0E-09, length = 1000)
y <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 1000)

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  y[i] <- error_f(x[i])
}

result <- tibble(x = x, y = y)
plot(result)
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEoTd.png)

The problem is, when I run the `optim` function with "Brent" method (or the `optimize` function, the result is the same), I cannot get the minimum value. I tried several pairs of "lower" and "upper" constraints, and even tried to set the initial value (par) to 1.8E-09, which is known to be very close to the answer. In any case, the result is like

```
Z <- optim(par = 1.8E-09,
           fn = error_f,
           lower = 1.0E-10,
           upper = 1.0E-08,
           method = "Brent",
           )

Z
$par
[1] 3.881464e-09

$value
[1] 2.50269e-17

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Check out the options for `reltol` in the `?optim` help page. Basically the number you are trying to get is smaller than the relative tolerance over which these algorithms will look for solutions. It just tries to get within `reltol` of the correct answer. The default is usually around 1e-8 because floating point math isn't that precise at that scale.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick ! I hadn't paied any attention to `reltol`.  By adding `control = list(reltol = 1.0E-10)` the code worked and found the answer $par = 1.819E-09. It really helped!